# Which motor wire corresponds to which phase

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, wiring, three-phase

I have a three phase motor having 3 wires: red, black and white. But the product datasheet does not tell us which colour wire corresponds to which phase.

Comment: Please contact the supplier of the motor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain it's a three phase motor, and a three phase supply, of the correct voltage, then ...

- Disconnect the motor from what it's driving, so that if it spins the wrong way, nothing gets damaged.
- Connect the three phase wires at random.
- If the motor spins the wrong way, switch two of the wires.

But with wire colours like that, it doesn't sound like a three phase motor.